# Getting warning in console while upgrading weblogic: Cannot add Jersey servlet for application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, weblogic

when upgrading from weblogic from 12.1.3 to 12.2.1 we are getting below warnings in weblogic console logs. Jersey version we are using is 2.26 and spring 4.

While using jersey-spring4 as a dependency, as application path is already set still its showing these warnings.

**Warning**

- Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.
- Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.*.*._ because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.
- Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.

I tried below code sample to fix it but still its showing these warning :

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig
{
    /**
     * Instantiates a new application config.
     */
    public ApplicationConfig()
    {
        // packages to scan
        packages("com._._.be.ws");
        register(new UnmarshallExceptionMapper());
        register(new BadRequestExceptionMapper());
        register(JaxbJsonProvider.class);
        register(new CacheResponseFilter("no-cache"));
        
        // register the XML validation
        register(XmlValidationHandler.getInstance().getResolver());
    }
} 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com._._.be.ws.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Backend/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please help if you face this issue earlier.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com._._._ because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
\n<Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? We have the same problem...

Comment: @Jaroslav No ..